# Dynamic model generation based on a metadata table in dbt

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am new to dbt and am looking to explore it to build an incremental load from *"source"* to *"staging"* schema. The *"source"* schema is incremental data from the source on a batch_id and *"staging"* is the merged/upsert data with one row per source-primary-key. Problem is I have over 40 tables and I don't want to manually create 40 .sql files to generate the model. Can anyone point me in the direction of *dynamic model creation*? I do have the following code written, but I don't know where it should go so that when I issue a dbt run, it takes the info from the *metadata_tbl* and creates the model dynamically. My schemas reside in a Snowflake DB. Thanks in advance for all the suggestions.

```
{# OBTAIN TABLES TO BE PROCESSED FROM THE METADATA TABLE #}
{%- call statement('tgt_tbl_info', fetch_result=True) -%}
    select target_schema,
            target_table_name,
            primary_key,
            stg_schema_name
    from {{ source('admin','smetadata’_tbl) }}
    where source_system = 'TEST_INCR'
    order by target_table_name
{%- endcall -%}

{%- set tgt_tbl_name = load_result('tgt_tbl_info') -%}

{%- set tgt_tbl_name_data = tgt_tbl_name['data']-%}


{# LOOP THROUGH THE TABLES TO INCREMENTALLY LOAD THEM #}
{% for tgt_tbl_name in tgt_tbl_name_data %}
    --select {{tgt_tbl_name[0]}}, {{tgt_tbl_name[1]}}
    {{
    config(
        materialized='incremental',
        unique_key='{{tgt_tbl_name[2]}}'
    )
    }}
    
    {# OBTAIN MAX BATCH ID IN THE SOURCE SCHEMA #}
    with src_max_batch as
    (
        select {{tgt_tbl_name[2]}} as src_id, 
                max(batch_id) as src_max_batch_id
        from {{tgt_tbl_name[0]}}.{{tgt_tbl_name[1]}}
        group by {{tgt_tbl_name[2]}}
    ),

    {# OBTAIN MAX BATCH ID IN THE STAGING SCHEMA #}
    stg_max_batch as
    (
        select {{tgt_tbl_name[2]}} as stg_id, 
                max(batch_id) as stg_max_batch_id
        from {{tgt_tbl_name[3]}}.{{tgt_tbl_name[1]}}
        group by {{tgt_tbl_name[2]}}
    ),

    {# OBTAIN ROWS FROM SOURCE SCHEMA THAT NEED TO BE PROCESSED INTO STAGING SCHEMA #}
    to_process as
    (
        select src_id as process_id,
                src_max_batch_id as process_batch_id
        from src_max_batch
            left outer join stg_max_batch 
                on src_id = stg_id
        where src_max_batch_id > IFNULL(stg_max_batch_id,0)
    ),

    final as
    (
        select *
        from {{tgt_tbl_name[0]}}.{{tgt_tbl_name[1]}}
            inner join to_process
                on {{tgt_tbl_name[2]}} = process_id
                and batch_id = process_batch_id
    )

    select *
    from final

    {% if is_incremental() %}

    --where batch_id > (select max(batch_id) from {{ this }}
        where {{tgt_tbl_name[2]}} in (select id from final)

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you looked at creating custom materializations [here](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/guides/creating-new-materializations)?

Comment: Thanks for showing the way @Kay. I will take a look and see how I could possibly use this.

Comment: @NBaliga - Did you created generalised solution for the above ask? If yes, then you will add your solution. It will be helpful for me to use it.

Comment: @ThangaduraiNainamalai unfortunately I did not have much time to R&D the solution of creating custom materialization but I found a shortcut - cloned the git repo, copy-pasted the folder that matches the definition I need, replaced model names using Atom (or any editor) and pushed changes to git to create a new model folder.

Comment: @ThangaduraiNainamalai apologies for the really late response. Instead of using dbt, a team member was able to write a script in python that connects to snowflake to get the table schema and then generate the model files for all the tables in a schema.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Materializations that dbt offers, here is an example and link to the dbt documentation:https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/guides/creating-new-materializations

```
{%- materialization my_view, default -%}

{%- set target_relation = api.Relation.create(
    identifier=identifier, schema=schema, database=database,
    type='view') -%}

-- ... setup database ...
-- ... run pre-hooks...

-- build model
{% call statement('main') -%}
{{ create_view_as(target_relation, sql) }}
{%- endcall %}

-- ... run post-hooks ...
-- ... clean up the database...

-- Return the relations created in this materialization
{{ return({'relations': [target_relation]}) }}

{%- endmaterialization -%}
```